# Обновление значение при помощи AJAX

Tags: javascript, ajax

Есть функция:

```
    (function poll() {
    setTimeout(function() {
    $.ajax({
        type: "GET",
        url: "/api/system",
        processData: true,
        dataType: 'text',
        cache: false,
        success: function (data, textStatus, request) {
            var system = jQuery.parseJSON(data);
            $(".uptime").var(system.uptime);
            $(".system-uptime").var(system.systemUptime);

        }
    });
  }, 1000);
})();
```

она получает данные из JSON, обрабатывает и заменяет значение в `".uptime"` и `".system-uptime"`. По идеи, это происходит каждую секунду, значение 1000(мс). Что у меня получается: Я получаю данные, они появляются на веб-странице, но не обновляются через каждую секунду, хотя в консоли эта функция вызывается. Как решить эту проблему? Можно ли обойти все это на подобии:

```
(function poll() {
    setTimeout(function() {
    $.ajax({
        type: "GET",
        url: "/api/system",
        processData: true,
        dataType: 'text',
        cache: false,
        success: function (data, textStatus, request) {
            var system = jQuery.parseJSON(data);
            $("input[id='uptime']").val(system.uptime);
            $("input[id='sysUptime']").val(system.systemUptime);
        }
    });
  }, 1000);
})();
```

однако не при помощи input.

Comment: На всякий случай уточню: в первом блоке кода, у вас `.var` вместо `.val`. Не в этом проблема?

Comment: @DmitriySimushev нет, проблема не в этом

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
setTimeout() -- функция вызываеться один раз, через заданный промежуток времени
Вам нужно использовать функцию setInterval()
```

Comment: данные не выводятся. заменил на `.val` - аналогично.

Comment: Посмотрите в консоли, данные приходят с через каждую секунду?

Comment: да, данные приходят через каждую секунду

Comment: теперь попробуйте просто в консоли поменять данные. $('.uptime').val('Blablabla');
И еще у вас поле ввода с классом uptime или с id? Судя по второму примеру у вас id=uptime. Тогда надо делать $('#uptime').val('Blalala')

Comment: сейчас проверить не могу. пример с ID; был написан только как пример, в коде он отсутствует.